# getting the user input in edit text control in mono android (C#)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

i have written a simple android app to test the mono android in c#.
my program is that there is an Edit Text control(or plain text which was the name of the control when i was creating the UI in main.axml file) and there is a button.user type something in the edit text and press the button and all i want is to get the user input.but i cannot access it via the Text property.

side note: my main program is to send this text via Socket to a server but when i want to get the string and put it into a buffer it always returns nothing.
here is my test program:

```
     protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle) {
         base.OnCreate(bundle);
         SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
         EditText input = FindViewById(Resource.Id.editText1);
         Button send = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
         send.Click += (sender, e) => {             
              string str = input.Text;
         };
     }
```

and here is my actual socket program:

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        EditText iptext = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editText1);
        EditText porttext = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editText2);
        EditText input = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editText3);
        Button send = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
        send.Click += (sender, e) => {
            *connetpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(iptext.Text) ,Convert.ToInt32(porttext.Text));
            sc.Connect(connetpoint);
            sendbuffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input.Text);
            sc.Send(sendbuffer);
        };

    }
```

but the strange part is that the * line works perfectly in which i get the other 2 edit text input(ip and port of the server).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a problem with your code and cannot recreate your issue. The following code works both on Emulator and on device:

```
var button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.MyButton);
var et1 = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editText1);
var et2 = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editText2);
var et3 = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editText3);

button.Click += (s,e) =>
{
    var text1 = et1.Text;
    var text2 = et2.Text;
    var text3 = et3.Text;
    Toast.MakeText(this, string.Format("T1: {0}, T2: {1}, T3: {2}", text1, text2, text3), ToastLength.Short).Show();
};
```

How are you verifying that the `EditText` actually have values in them? It could be the debugger having a bad time for some reason and reporting it being empty, while actually not being empty. In such cases I would report it to Xamarin.

Comment: thanks.my problem is solved by using the var type for getting the text